# When built from eclipse, why is a java program slower than when built from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, command-line

I did some simple function call and string operation in a loop, the java program runs much faster under command line than launching ( Run as... ) from eclipse...

6 lines of output were printed, each line is around 120 characters.
each line is a perf result ranges from 50ms to 300ms.

The total time is a little more than 2 seconds.

"much slower" here means, for certain operations ( function call ), I see 20ms vs 300 ms.

After running on console once, the speed on eclipse catches up!

After I change and build the code in eclipse, the speed on CL will drop if I don't rebuild it with command line.

Looks like some hotspot information is only generated with CL...

Comment: Is your program generating a lot of output and being captured by the console window in Eclipse?  That will slow things down, since it has to capture, parse, and display output in a scrollable GUI window, whereas running it normally just dumps to size-limited DOS window.

Comment: Maybe you're printing lots of output to the console, and the command prompt window can process that faster than the Eclipse output window.

Comment: Could you narrow down "much faster"? How long does it take to run (approximately) from the command line vs. through Eclipse?

Comment: If you have multiple jvm's/jdk's installed then your eclipse might be using one that is different to the one that is being run from the command line.

Comment: The difference you're seeing is unlikely to result from GUI console output of just 6 lines.

I believe Eclipse internally uses a different compiler than the JDK compiler.  When you run from the command line, do you do a separate compile using the Sun/Oracle compiler?  Are those class files in your classpath for Eclipse?  If so, that might explain everything.

Comment: I did a separate compile using the same input ( files/ jars ). How could I figure out if the compilers are different? [ But please remember, when the program run once on Console, the speed in Eclipse also boost up!]

Comment: @Tom: Sounds like an issue of Eclipse getting initialized to run the first time.  You can use something like `DateTime.currentTimeMillis()` to get a start time and end time, and calculate the difference to get the actual runtime in milliseconds.  This will eliminate time from Eclipse initialization, etc.  Report back on the timings between the two if you can.

Comment: @mellamokb The program can run at consistent slow speed as long as it is launched from eclipse and the CL version has not run. So it is not about 1st time or 2nd time. The Timing is get by System.nanoTime(..) in each function, instead of the whole program. So program loading is not an issue here.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode when you run from Eclipse?

Comment: Definitely NOT in debug mode. Also, after the program run once under CL, eclipse's speed will catch up to the same level.

Comment: When you compile externally, where do you put the .class files?  In the same place that Eclipse normally puts them, or somewhere else?

Comment: They are built in the same place and their output are different. What might be the reason?

Comment: The issue description is a bit confusing. What exactly do you need to do to get the code to run 'fast' in Eclipse? Compiling it with Command Line? Running it with Command Line? Or both? Can you reproduce the slow/fast transitions and vice versa repeatingly, or do you encounter any random influence on execution speed?

Comment: Both. After doing both, eclipse runs faster until you rebuild it in eclipse. It is very deterministic, repros every time.

Comment: Is eclipse still using the jikes compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just the eclipse console that is slower than your operating systems console?
Plus, at a total runtime of ~2 seconds, your benchmark probably is just super inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the culprit is memory usage as a result of Eclipse loading, with the possibility that Eclipse is also doing something additional to the executable like swapping class loaders, or starting the java debugger.

I would say the most likely answer however is simply: Eclipse uses a lot of resources, especially memory, and is starving the system a bit, leading to swapping, and decreased performance.  YMMV, and there's no guarantee I'm right without seeing your system, it's just my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with other comments that Eclipse is doing something when running the application and printing the console.

Eclipse has its own compiler (usually referred as Eclipse JDT) which supports incremental compilation. There is a possibility that the binary compiled by Eclipse is not optimized as it is compiled by javac.

These two compiler serves different purpose, JDT mainly enable Eclipse to provide state-of-art refactoring and auto-completion, and javac spends a lot of effort doing optimization.

Comment: Cool. do you have any references/link we can check?

Comment: Tom, you can check Eclipse JDT at http://eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php. According to the description: "An incremental Java compiler. Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it is based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler. In particular, it allows to run and debug code which still contains unresolved errors."

And I do not understand why you need to care about performance of code compiled by Ecilpse. I think people will recompile the code using their favourite build tools (Ant / Maven) for actual distribution, and that is compiled by javac.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it's understandable that the application would run slower with all the Eclipse baggage underneath.  Eclipse spawns the JVM process as a child and I am sure still does its own 'magic'.